# Simulation of satellite transmission on MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am relatively new to MATLAB and self-learning. I am trying to accomplish running a simulation of a satellite transmission and re-transmission on Matlab via selective repeat ARQ. The problem with the code is that. when I enter the data sequence length and the number of packets after running the code.

I get an error message for line 11: a=x(i,j); for certain values of data sequence length and number of packets.

And if i switch the values i get an error message for line 15: pac(i,:)=[x(i,:),p(i)];

How can I solve this issue of getting errors due to the code? when via research I discovered it's the correct way for it to be written?

```
% program for protocol analysis
clc; close all;
n=input('Enter the data sequence length');
m=input('Enter the number of packets ');
x=randi(m,n);
% make packet

p=zeros(1,m);
for i=1:m
    for j=1:n
        a=x(i,j);
        b=p(i);
        p(i)=bitxor(a,b);
    end
   pac(i,:)=[x(i,:),p(i)];
   subplot(m,1,i); stem(pac(i,:));
end
xlabel('Transmitted Data,last bit is the parity bit');
% send first group of packets
% send packets
figure
ba=m/8;
for k=1:m
%     for l=1:8
%         g=l*k;
        data(k,:)=bsc(pac(k,:),.1);
        subplot(m,1,k); stem(data(k,:));
%     end

end
xlabel('Recieved Data,last bit is the parity bit');
figure

err = 1;
erf=1;

while (err~=0)
    do=data(:,n+1)';
    err=bitxor(p,do);
    stem(err);
    display(err);
    ('displaying retransmitted packets');

    for i=1:m
        if err(1,i)== 1
            display(err);
             ('error detected in packet no:');(i);

%             figure
            for j=i:m
                data(j,:)=bsc(pac(j,:),.1);

%                 subplot(m,1,j);stem(data(j,:));
            end

        end
        do=data(:,n+1)';
        err=bitxor(p,do);

    end
end
% figure
% for g=1:m
%     subplot(m,1,g);stem(data(g,:));
% end
% xlabel('Finally Received data after retransmission, last bit is the parity bit');
```

Comment: Which values cause you problems? If I use values `n=5; m=5;` it crashes at `data(j,:)=bsc(pac(j,:),.1);`.

Comment: Another thing, `erf` is the error function and it is therefore bad practice to overwrite it with `erf=1;`

Comment: What is the error? The error message does explain the reason, you need to show that

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the variable x is intended to be a matrix of dimensions m times n.
The function

```
 x = randi(m,n);
```

however, creates a square matrix of dimensions n times n.
What you want is probably

```
x = randi([minval maxval],m,n);
```

where you fill in the minimum and maximum values that x may have,